# Is there a way to scale down an image, preserving its ratio, inside a div element using CSS correctly?

Tags: html, css

I've been having trouble fitting images into a `<div>` element on my site. I've tried several different methods, including setting `max-width` and `max-height` to `100%`, changing the object that it's contained inside to display as a `flex` object, and various different `object-fit` parameters. Is there something that I'm missing here, or is it impossible to do this?

```js
openModal();

function openModal() {
  modal.style.display = "flex";
  var t = setTimeout(transitionOpenModal, 30);
}

function transitionOpenModal() {
  modal.style.opacity = "1";
  modalContainer.style.transform = "scale(100%)";
  modalContainer.style.webkitTransform = "scale(1)";
}

function closeModal() {
  modalContainer.style.transform = "scale(0%)";
  modalContainer.style.webkitTransform = "scale(0)";
  modal.style.opacity = "0";
  var t = setTimeout(closeModalAfterTransition, 250);
}

function closeModalAfterTransition() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
/* MODAL DIALOG */

.modal {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  transition: opacity 0.25s;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.modal-header {
  position: sticky;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}

.modal-container {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  max-width: 80vw;
  max-height: 80vh;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
  transform: scale(0%);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform 0.25s;
}

.modal-content {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

img.modal-content-inner {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.modal-header>h2 {
  display: inline;
}

.modal-close {
  float: right;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.modal-close:hover,
.modal-close:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="modal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-container" id="modal-container">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h2 id="modal-title">modal</h2>
      <span class="modal-close" id="modal-close">&times;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-content" id="modal-content">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.png">
      <!-- this is a test case, please try with multiple image sizes -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here's what it currently looks like on my site.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35V8F.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this one out on my own—turns out I could just set the `max-width` and `max-height` of the image itself.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the img max-width:100% should do the trick. This will constrain it to the width of the containing div. Here's a stripped down version of what you have.

```css
  .modal {
          /* display: none; */
          /* opacity: 0; */
          position: fixed;
          z-index: 99;
          left: 0;
          top: 0;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          overflow: hidden;
          background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
          backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
          -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
          transition: opacity 0.25s;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
      }

      .modal-header {
          position: sticky;
          padding-bottom: 16px;
      }

      .modal-container {
          background-color: white;
          border-radius: 4px;
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;
          padding: 16px;
          max-width: 80vw;
          /* max-height: 80vh; */
          filter: drop-shadow(0 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.25));
          /* transform: scale(0%);
          -webkit-transform: scale(0);
          transition: transform 0.25s; */
      }

      .modal-content {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
      }

      .modal-content > img {
          max-width: 100%;
      }

      .modal-header > h2 {
          display: inline;
      }

      .modal-close {
          float: right;
          font-size: 24px;
          font-weight: bold;
      }

      .modal-close:hover, .modal-close:focus {
          text-decoration: none;
          cursor: pointer;
      }
```

```html
<div id="modal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-container" id="modal-container">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h2 id="modal-title">modal</h2>
          <span class="modal-close" id="modal-close">&times;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-content" id="modal-content">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, unfortunately--the image that I'm testing this with (in this case, it's 1920x1080) still bleeds off the bottom of the modal dialog. It does resize to fit the width of the div, however.

Comment: which part is the modal dialog? What do you mean by bleeds off?

Comment: The "modal-container" div is the dialog; the outer one is the background that contains the dialog (shamelessly referenced from w3schools, if you're looking for a cleaner source).

Comment: ok I see what's happening. The containing div is too small for the img. You can either remove the max-height constraint or set the img as a background img. See my updated answer

Comment: This worked, but now the modal dialog is too big to fit on screen when it's displaying certain large images (for example, a 1024x1024 image that I added pushes the title bar off the screen). I want the to be dialog fully visible at all times.